# error when using slick slider on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to apply the Slick Slider plugin in my project. the plugin works ok when it's applied to just 1 element. but when I try to apply it to more than 1 element, it only works for the 1st element in the script.. after that it returns an error `_.$slides is null`. [Tarnjeet Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41694724/1235167) said it might be because there are multiple slick slider script in the page, but I checked and there's only 1 script call. what am I doing wrong here?

my HTML looks like this:

```
<section class="gallery-slide slider use-slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="my-slide-img" 
            style="background-image: url('/assets/img/gallery/2010/img-0001.jpg');"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="my-slide-img" 
            style="background-image: url('/assets/img/gallery/2010/img-0002.jpg');"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="other-slide slider use-slider">
    <div class="slide fc02">
        <a href="#" target="_blank()">
            <div class="other-slide-img" 
            style="background-image: url('/assets/img/cover/img-1001.jpg');">
            </div>

            <div class="other-slide-title">My First Post</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide fc02">
        <a href="#" target="_blank()">
            <div class="other-slide-img" 
            style="background-image: url('/assets/img/cover/img-1002.jpg');">
            </div>

            <div class="other-slide-title">My Second Post</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

and this is the script I've tried.. I even tried using each as advised by [kanudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35620686/1235167)

```
$('.use-slider').each(function(key, item) {
    var selector = 'slider_'+key.toString();

    $(this).attr('id', selector);

    var sliderID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(sliderID).hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
        $(sliderID).slick({
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2500,
            arrows: false,
            dots: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 520,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    }
    else if ($(sliderID).hasClass('other-slide')) {
        $(sliderID).slick({
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 2500,
            arrows: false,
            dots: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 520,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by using a more specific selector. it turns out the script DID run more than once so the same element was affected twice.. that's what was causing the `_.$slides is null` error. so everytime the slick plugin is applied to an element, I needed to remove the `use-slider` class to make sure that element will only be affected once.

here's how my script looks like now. in case anyone have the same problem.

```
$('.gallery-slide.use-slider').each(function(key, item) {
  var selector = 'gallery_slider-' + key;
  $(this).attr('id', selector);
  var sliderID = '#' + selector;
  $(sliderID).slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    .. (other slick slider parameters)
  });
  $(sliderID).removeClass('use-slider');
});

$('.other-slide.use-slider').each(function(key, item) {
  var selector = 'other_slider-' + key;
  $(this).attr('id', selector);
  var sliderID = '#' + selector;
  $(sliderID).slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    .. (other slick slider parameters)
  });
  $(sliderID).removeClass('use-slider');
});
```